# Firestore cannot be activated for this product

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm simply trying to create a new Firestore bucket. I've done this before, but now I'm getting a very unspecific error (for 2 days now). Unfortunately the image is in German. It translates to

"Firestore cannot be activated for this project. An unknown error has occurred"

Any idea what could be the problem?

more context:

- I tried this with 2 independent gmail accounts (same error)
- It works for my third gmail account (as mentioned above) --> maybe I need to configure something in these gmail accounts? (one of them is a company account of which I'm not the administrator, the other one is a private account (as the one with which everything is working)
- I always disable google analytics
- I chose a european server in the dropdown[image]

Comment: Did you try to use a different server?

Comment: To get the Firebase console in English, ad `?hl=en` to the URL.

Comment: yes, I tried the US server as well, same issue.

Comment: @mcExchange, have you also tried using a different browser? Have you also tried deleting the project through this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects?_ga=2.43334688.400614276.1678286806-2038976986.1678286806) and creating another one through this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/welcome?_ga=2.81733266.400614276.1678286806-2038976986.1678286806) and selecting **Datastore Mode**?